# Button at the end of array in AutoIT

Tags: windows, autoit

I am working on a program that pulls data from AD via a linked table in SQL and lets the user copy an email address to the clipboard. I am using an array to dynamically display a button beside each row. The problem is that, when I try and put labels or buttons inside the for loop, they don't show up. Is it just that I'm doing it wrong. My code is as follows:

```
 #include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
 #include <mssql.au3>
 #include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
 #include <Array.au3>
 #include <WindowsConstants.au3>
 global $title = "E-Mail address lookup"
 global $sqlCon = _MSSQL_Con("server", "user", "Directory3=", "password")
 global $name = InputBox($title,"Please type the name of the person you wish to find")
 global $result = _MSSQL_GetRecord($sqlCon, "autoit_view","*", "WHERE cn LIKE '%" & StringStripWS($name,3) & "%'")
 if StringLen(StringStripWS($name,3)) < 1 then
      MsgBox(0, $title, "Name cannot be empty")
 Else
 Global $ControlID = GUICreate($title, 530, 500)
 GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
 Local $iOldOpt = Opt("GUICoordMode", 2)
 GUICtrlCreateLabel("  ", 0, 0, 80)
 GUICtrlCreateLabel("E-Mail Address", 20, -1, 100)
 GUICtrlCreateLabel("Name", 20, -1, 50)
 GUICtrlCreateLabel("Department", 20, -1, 100)
 GUICtrlCreateLabel("Telephone Number", 20, -1, 200)
 for $i = 1 To UBound($result) Step 1
      GUICtrlCreateButton("Copy", 0, $i, 30, 20)
 Next
 GUISetState()

 While 1
      Global $Msg = GUIGetMsg()
      Switch $Msg
           Case -3, $ControlID
        Exit
      EndSwitch
 WEnd
EndIf
```

I would have expected one button to show up on a new line on every iteration of the loop

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use another mode:

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
;~  #include <mssql.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
Global $title = "E-Mail address lookup"
;~  global $sqlCon = _MSSQL_Con("server", "user", "Directory3=", "password")
;~  global $name = InputBox($title,"Please type the name of the person you wish to find")
;~  global $result = _MSSQL_GetRecord($sqlCon, "autoit_view","*", "WHERE cn LIKE '%" & StringStripWS($name,3) & "%'")
Global $result = StringSplit('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8', ',')
;~  if StringLen(StringStripWS($name,3)) < 1 then
;~       MsgBox(0, $title, "Name cannot be empty")
;~  Else

;~ _ArrayDisplay($result)
Global $ControlID = GUICreate($title, 530, 500)
;~ Local $iOldOpt = Opt("GUICoordMode", 2)
GUICtrlCreateLabel("  ", 0, 0, 80)
GUICtrlCreateLabel("E-Mail Address", 20, -1, 100)
GUICtrlCreateLabel("Name", 20, -1, 50)
GUICtrlCreateLabel("Department", 20, -1, 100)
GUICtrlCreateLabel("Telephone Number", 20, -1, 200)
For $i = 1 To UBound($result) - 1
    GUICtrlCreateButton("Copy", 20, $i * 20, 350, 20)
Next

GUISetState()

While 1
    $Msg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $Msg
        Case -3, $ControlID
            Exit
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```